# Element height dependant on parent instead of content?

Tags: html, css, height

I have 3 containers, one is Total (Red border) and inside it we have Left (Yellow border, containing image) and Right (Blue border, containing text).

The Left is set to roughly 30%, with float: left; while the Right is set to 70% with float: right;

Now, what I am trying to achieve is the following: I want both to have the height of the Total, while total still somehow being dependent on the content - so I can center the position the content of both Left and Right into the middle of Total (Red) with margin-top, margin-bottom = auto;

1) I can't put fixed height on Total, which does fix the height, but the content spills over when narrow (otherwise it's just ridiculously empty).

2) Here's the video of elements to get a clear picture of what I'm trying to achieve. I would also prefer that there is no js. https://my.mixtape.moe/kxoobz.webm

Comment: show your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) to achieve what you're wanting:

```css
.total {
  display: flex;
}

.red {
  border: 2px solid red;
  flex: 1 0 30%; /* fill 30% width */
}

.yellow {
  border: 2px solid yellow;
  flex: 1 0 70%;
}
```

```html
<div class="total">
  <div class="red">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150">
  </div>
  <div class="yellow">
    Quisque porttitor, ipsum vel elementum ultricies, magna arcu scelerisque massa, et laoreet elit felis nec urna. Praesent suscipit leo at ullamcorper rutrum. Suspendisse potenti. Phasellus pretium mauris id lacus dapibus finibus. Nunc placerat est quis nisi aliquet, ac aliquet leo sagittis. Donec quis aliquet neque. Suspendisse potenti. In vestibulum nisl ut risus fermentum tempor sed at arcu. Aenean at ante turpis. Integer nec dolor placerat diam vulputate consequat. Cras consectetur mi scelerisque massa accumsan auctor. Nunc imperdiet lacus eget justo luctus molestie. In dignissim lectus eget feugiat tincidunt. Vestibulum tempus est risus, eget suscipit turpis molestie id.
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Holy smokes, I thought I'll have to use overflow: hidden; but this works!